# Dropdown menu hiding behind slideshow

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, z-index

I have an issue related to dropdown menu that remains behind Lean Slider. Please help me how to fix this issue. I am pasting html and css code here that you see where there is a problem.

```
I have tried to change z-index, but nothing changed.

HTML:

    <pre><div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>About us</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>

   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Programs</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Submenu</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>

   <li><a href="#">News</a></li>    
   <li><a href="#">Network</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
</div><code>




I am also pasting CSS code here.

    <pre>#cssmenu {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  background: #2b2f3a;
  width: auto;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 500;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 17px 12px;
  color: #559c00;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 32px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #72cc00;
}
#cssmenu li.has-sub::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub::after {
  right: 15px;
  top: 20px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #559c00;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover::after {
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
}
#indicatorContainer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}
#pIndicator {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #2b2f3a;
  z-index: -2;
  -webkit-transition: left .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: left .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: left .25s ease;
  -o-transition: left .25s ease;
  transition: left .25s ease;
}
#cIndicator {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #2b2f3a;
  top: -12px;
  right: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: 70px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: 37px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  top: 44px;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 210px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 170px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  width: 170px;
  margin-right: 3px;

  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #559c00;
  font-weight:bold;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .35s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .35s ease;
  -o-transition: all .35s ease;
  transition: all .35s ease;


  box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #818181; /*shadow for CSS3 capable browsers.*/
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #818181;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #818181;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li a {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
  background: #fff;
  color: #72cc00;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last > a {
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul::after {
  content: '';
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom-color: #559c00;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  left: 30px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > ul::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 30px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub::after {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #9ea2a5;
  right: 10px;
  top: 12px;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease, right 0.2s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub::after {
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #9ea2a5;
  right: auto;
  left: 10px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover::after {
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
  right: -5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub:hover::after {
  border-right-color: #ffffff;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  left: -5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu {
    width: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenuArrow,
  #cssmenu #indicatorContainer {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul {
    height: auto;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu li,
  #cssmenu > ul > li {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul > li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul > li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul > li:hover > ul {
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    right: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu ul .has-sub::after {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a {
    padding: 12px 20px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    width: auto;
    padding: 8px 35px;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul li a {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
    background: none;
    color: #8c9195;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 50px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 65px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 80px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 95px;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > #menu-button {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button > a {
    padding: 14px 20px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul.open li,
  #cssmenu > ul.open > li {
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul.open > li#menu-button > a {
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.1);
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul::after {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #559c00;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #559c00;
    right: 20px;
    top: 15px;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #559c00;
    right: 20px;
    top: 25px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul.open #menu-button::after,
  #cssmenu ul.open #menu-button::before {
    border-color: #fff;
  }
}
<code>
```

I'll be happy if you help me how to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am pasting the site url here that you can see visually.
http://www.jaazerbaijan.org/

Comment: Could you please tell me where I have to create a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You have apply `overflow:hidden` for the `wrapper` class. For that reason it is hiding the submenus. Add the following style in your CSS, hopefully it will fix the issue.

```
  header > div.wrapper:first-child
 {
   overflow:visible !important;
 }
```

NOTE: You can try without `!important` keyword, if it is not working then apply it like above. Because i am not sure about the order of your CSS written.

Comment: if this answer helps kindly accept it using tick mark, so that it will help for other users.